# Maven use properties into relativePath

Tags: java, maven, svn, pom.xml

I've a maven project that references a module (subproject), the subproject has parent section with relativePath specify to `../pom.xml` and when I Build from my developer machine all works fine.

On my SVN the folder structure is little bit difference, my subproject folder contains **trunk** folder and inside this folder there are my sources.

My folder structure on SVN:

```
project
|
|-- pom.xml
|-- subproject
    |-- trunk
        |-- pom.xml
        |-- src
```

If I want build my project on my CI (teamcity) server i need to change the `relativePath` to `../../pom.xml`. Are there other solutions to do that without edit pom.xml ? Can I pass a property from command line to `relativePath` ? I've tried this way but my input property is ignored.

---

Thanks

Comment: Change the structure accordingly to your project structure makes working with SVN easier and with the project as well as with Maven. The SVN structure violates best practices in SVN which means having a trunk/tags/branches for each project separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a "mvn install -pl ." on the folder containing the parent pom first (i.e., from the project directory in your svn structure) then do a maven build of your subproject, the subproject will not need the relative path line at all. You can leave it but it will get skipped since the installed version will be found by maven first from the repo.  The "-pl ." option tells maven not to build the submodules, just install the parent pom in the local repo.